# Firestore Web V9 Live display a real-time list of documents Reactjs Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, rxjs

Good afternoon,

I am using React 18, Firebase 9.13 and @google-cloud/firestore 6.4.1 .  I am working on storing an array of messages in a useState array.  I am able to pull in the data iniitally with my code below, but whenever an update is made in the DB, my array is reset to only the docs within the docChanges() call.  I have put logs throughout the code and it looks like the state is saved until I jump back into the onSnapShot code block.  Please let me know if I can provide anymore information.

```
export const ChatRoom = (roomProps: chatRoomProps) => {
  const messagesRef = collection(db, 'messages');
  const [messagelist, setMessagelist] = useState<DocumentData[]>([]); 

  useEffect(() => {
    const q = query(messagesRef, limit(25));
    const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
      const messagesHolder: DocumentData[] = [];
      querySnapshot.docChanges().forEach((doc) => {
        console.log('changes'); 
        messagesHolder.push(doc.doc.data());
      });
      setMessagelist([...messagelist, ...messagesHolder]);
    });

    return () => {
      console.log('unsub');
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);  
  
  return (
    <>
      <main>
        {messagelist.map((msg) => { 
          return <ChatMessage uid={msg.uid} photoURL={msg.photoURL} message={msg.message} />;
        })}
        <span ref={scrollRef}></span>
      </main>
      <form className="chat_form" onSubmit={sendMessage}>
        <input
          className="chat_input"
          value={formValue}
          onChange={(e) => setFormValue(e.target.value)}
          placeholder="say something."
        ></input>
        <button className="chat_button" type="submit">
          Submit
        </button>
      </form>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Please edit your question providing a screenshot of your database structure so that we could see what we could optimize.

Comment: @RobertG Some more information was provided.  Do you think this is somehow related to the DB Setup?  I did not consider that.

Comment: I fixed the loop by using  querySnapshot.docChanges() instead of just querySnapshot!  My messages UseState is however being reset anytime the onSnapshot is called again :( after an update from myself or a different user it pulls in the correct change document, but reverts back to my useState initialization.  Updated Code in post.